# Start xtick labels in the first interval using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I'm creating a graph with two x axis using `pgfplots` where one axis represents timesteps and the other iterations within one timestep. So far I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=27,
                 ymin=300, ymax=450,
                 xtick={7,12,17,22,27},
                 xticklabels={1,2,...,5},
                 x tick label as interval, % <-----
                 xmajorgrids,
                 axis x line*=top,
                 hide y axis,
                 xlabel={Timestep}
                 ]
    \end{axis}
    %
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=27,
                 ymin=300, ymax=450,
                 axis x line*=bottom,
                 xtick={1,2,...,26},
                 xticklabels= {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5},
                 xlabel={Newton-Iterations},
                 ylabel={GMRes-Iterations},
                 ]
                 \addplot[mark=none, red] table [x index=2,y index=5]
                    {data};
                 \addplot[mark=none, blue] table [x index=2,y index=8]
                    {data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which results in the following figure:
[image]

So far so good. For the axis on top I use `x tick label as interval` but as you can see it starts in the second interval. Can I move these labels, so that they start in the first?

Comment: `xtick={1,7,12,17,22,27},`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @PaulGessler, that did the trick. Obviously I lost sight of the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `x tick label as interval`, it is necessary to have n+1 positions in `xtick` in order to place n `xticklabels`. There is an extra position needed because we need to mark the start and end of each 'interval'. So adding the start of the first label (`1`) is sufficient:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=27,
                 ymin=300, ymax=450,
                 xtick={1,7,12,17,22,27},
                 xticklabels={1,2,...,5},
                 x tick label as interval, % <-----
                 xmajorgrids,
                 axis x line*=top,
                 hide y axis,
                 xlabel={Timestep}
                 ]
    \end{axis}
    %
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=27,
                 ymin=300, ymax=450,
                 axis x line*=bottom,
                 xtick={1,2,...,26},
                 xticklabels= {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5},
                 xlabel={Newton-Iterations},
                 ylabel={GMRes-Iterations},
                 ]
                 \addplot[mark=none, red] table [x index=2,y index=5]
                    {data};
                 \addplot[mark=none, blue] table [x index=2,y index=8]
                    {data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(This will give errors because I don't have your data, but it shows the axis labels as desired.)

[image]