# Show only every n-th xtick label when using 'x tick label as interval'

Tags: pgfplots, labels

This question results from the same problem I asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235039/start-xtick-labels-in-the-first-interval-using-pgfplots/235043#235043).

Now, I have to many data points to give every single one a tick label. For one axis (the one on the bottom) I could achieve what I want. But with the other I have problems and I think this is due to the fact, that I'm using `x tick label as interval`. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   1   440 440
2   2   407 424
3   3   395 426
4   4   382 427
5   5   375 427
6   6   366 427
1   7   391 423
2   8   378 395
3   9   376 396
4   10  366 396
5   11  357 396
1   12  339 389
2   13  333 372
3   14  317 372
4   15  298 372
5   16  279 372
1   17  253 368
2   18  248 352
3   19  236 351
4   20  167 351
5   21  166 351
1   22  158 347
2   23  120 319
3   24  115 319
4   25  109 319
5   26  108 319
1   27  105 314
2   28  115 293
3   29  108 293
4   30  108 292
5   31  103 293
1   32  102 289
2   33  108 268
3   34  100 268
4   35  98  270
5   36  99  269
1   37  94  266
2   38  102 250
3   39  92  250
4   40  95  251
5   41  93  251
1   42  91  249
2   43  96  236
3   44  93  237
4   45  89  238
5   46  85  241
1   47  85  237
2   48  93  233
3   49  85  232
4   50  87  232
5   51  84  232
1   52  85  232
}\data

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=52,
                 ymin=0, ymax=450,
                 xtick={1,7,12,17,22,...,52},
                 minor x tick num=2,
                 xticklabels={1,2,...,10},
                 x tick label as interval,
                 xmajorgrids,
                 axis x line*=top,
                 hide y axis,
                 xlabel={Timestep}
                 ]
    \end{axis}
    %
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=52,
                 ymin=0, ymax=450,
                 axis x line*=bottom,
                 xtick={1,6,11,16,21,...,52},
                 minor x tick num=4,
                 xticklabels= {1,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
                 xlabel={Newton-Iterations},
                 ylabel={GMRes-Iterations},
                 ]
                 \addplot[mark=none, red] table [x index=1,y index=2]
                    {\data};
                 \addplot[mark=none, blue] table [x index=1,y index=3]
                    {\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

For the x ticks on top of the figure I want to show every second label (This is just an example, my original data has about 50 timesteps). I was playing around with `minor x tick num` and so on but I couldn't get the result I want.

Notice, that the first timestep has one Newton iteration more than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xticklabel` instead of `xticklabels`:

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{mod(\ticknum+1,2)==0?int(\ticknum+1):}\pgfmathresult}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   1   440 440
2   2   407 424
3   3   395 426
4   4   382 427
5   5   375 427
6   6   366 427
1   7   391 423
2   8   378 395
3   9   376 396
4   10  366 396
5   11  357 396
1   12  339 389
2   13  333 372
3   14  317 372
4   15  298 372
5   16  279 372
1   17  253 368
2   18  248 352
3   19  236 351
4   20  167 351
5   21  166 351
1   22  158 347
2   23  120 319
3   24  115 319
4   25  109 319
5   26  108 319
1   27  105 314
2   28  115 293
3   29  108 293
4   30  108 292
5   31  103 293
1   32  102 289
2   33  108 268
3   34  100 268
4   35  98  270
5   36  99  269
1   37  94  266
2   38  102 250
3   39  92  250
4   40  95  251
5   41  93  251
1   42  91  249
2   43  96  236
3   44  93  237
4   45  89  238
5   46  85  241
1   47  85  237
2   48  93  233
3   49  85  232
4   50  87  232
5   51  84  232
1   52  85  232
}\data

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=52,
                 ymin=0, ymax=450,
                 xtick={1,7,12,17,22,...,52},
                 minor x tick num=2,
                 xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{mod(\ticknum+1,2)==0?int(\ticknum+1):}\pgfmathresult},
                 x tick label as interval,
                 xmajorgrids,
                 axis x line*=top,
                 hide y axis,
                 xlabel={Timestep}
                 ]
    \end{axis}
    %
    \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=52,
                 ymin=0, ymax=450,
                 axis x line*=bottom,
                 xtick={1,6,11,16,21,...,52},
                 minor x tick num=4,
                 xticklabels= {1,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
                 xlabel={Newton-Iterations},
                 ylabel={GMRes-Iterations},
                 ]
                 \addplot[mark=none, red] table [x index=1,y index=2]
                    {\data};
                 \addplot[mark=none, blue] table [x index=1,y index=3]
                    {\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```